# Spring Authorization Server 1.1.1 - Following guides, sid and auth_time are null in OIDC claims

Tags: spring, server, authorization, spring-authorization-server

I'm creating an identity-provider for my personal company/project, following guides found on the spring docs site, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-jpa.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-userinfo.html#how-to-userinfo).

I have successfully connected the spring authorization server to my database and am able to populate the JWT and Id Token with the metadata my services require.

I am customizing my token with the following, which may possibly be the issue.

```
    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtTokenCustomizer() {
        return (context) -> {
            Object principal = context.getPrincipal().getPrincipal();

            if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) {
                context.getClaims().claims((claims) -> {
                    if (principal instanceof UserPrincipal) {
                        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(context.getPrincipal().getAuthorities())
                                .stream()
                                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), Collections::unmodifiableSet));
                        claims.put("roles", roles);
                        claims.put("tenantId", ((UserPrincipal) principal).getTenantId());
                        claims.put("userId", ((UserPrincipal) principal).getUserId());
                    }
                });
            }

            if (OidcParameterNames.ID_TOKEN.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getTokenType().getValue())) {
                if (principal instanceof UserPrincipal) {
                    OidcUserInfo userInfo = userInfoService.loadUser(((UserPrincipal) principal).getUserId());
                    context.getClaims().claims(claims -> claims.putAll(userInfo.getClaims()));
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

I thought I was doing everything correctly but when spring cloud gateway attempts to refresh my token for me, I get a 500. The server error is stemming from the following block of code from the [JwtGenerator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/99cd1b8d1ebd280faac54ea27c92bd8dc376fa2d/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/token/JwtGenerator.java#L137) class.

```
 else if (AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN.equals(context.getAuthorizationGrantType())) {
                OidcIdToken currentIdToken = context.getAuthorization().getToken(OidcIdToken.class).getToken();
                claimsBuilder.claim("sid", currentIdToken.getClaim("sid"));
                claimsBuilder.claim(IdTokenClaimNames.AUTH_TIME, currentIdToken.<Date>getClaim(IdTokenClaimNames.AUTH_TIME));
            }
```

It's possible the spring docs guides are slightly outdated. I assumed since they never mention anything about the `sid` or `auth_time` claims, that they would have been generated automatically.

I can add them manually and resolve the issue but what I understand from these specific claims is that the values of these should not change from token to token when doing refreshes.

**Edit:** After finding that link for the JWTGenerator on GitHub, I realized they fixed this already in 1.1.2 a couple of days ago. Updated my spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server version to 3.1.3 and it technically resolves the null claims, but figure I'll still leave this open since it would be nice to have the `auth_time` claim done correctly if I want to do timed reauthentications.

Appreciate any feedback!

Comment: I also faced the exact same problem today. I wonder why sessioninformation is null when i can clearly see session id in the web details. Hopefully someone could answer it.

Comment: Please use springauthorizationserver tag in the question.